# Set default username and concatenate with ID

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

With the following code, how can I also add a username with a default value of "user" then the 'id' field in my database, so it becomes "user15" for the 15th user for example?

I'm not sure where to add the default username, and I'm not a 100% on the syntax.

**Clarification:** I want to have a static string ("user") and concatenate that with the auto incremented 'id' field in my database.

**UPDATE:** It seems it's not possible to concatenate the auto incremented value right away, so: any suggestions on how to generate a default username to begin with? Username field is UNIQUE.

```
    $firstname = $profile['first_name'];
    $lastname = $profile['last_name'];
    $email = $profile['email'];
    $picture = $profile['picture']['url'];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
            INSERT INTO users (
                firstname, 
                lastname, 
                email, 
                picture, 
                token
            ) 
            VALUES (
                :firstname, 
                :lastname, 
                :email, 
                :picture, 
                :token)"
            );
        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':picture', $picture);
        $stmt->bindParam(':token', $accessToken);

        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Thank you for registering";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;

} else {

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('mywebsite.com/fblogin/index.php', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

Comment: While it's not guaranteed to be unique, [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is probably a good start.  If you don't have millions of users, you probably won't ever run into a conflict.

Comment: UUID is also a option..  The duplication chance is around 0.00000000006 (6 × 10−11).

Comment: You could insert a record with a blank/null/whatever the default for the column is value for the username, then recall the insert ID, and then update the username.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested this in a comment but let me try an answer to flesh it out a bit more. Basically the idea is insert a new record, then grab the insert ID, and then update the record in question.

```
if (something_supposed_to_happen_here()) {
    $firstname = $profile['first_name'];
    $lastname = $profile['last_name'];
    $email = $profile['email'];
    $picture = $profile['picture']['url'];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
            INSERT INTO users (
                firstname, 
                lastname, 
                email, 
                picture, 
                token
            ) 
            VALUES (
                :firstname, 
                :lastname, 
                :email, 
                :picture, 
                :token)"
            );
        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':picture', $picture);
        $stmt->bindParam(':token', $accessToken);

        $stmt->execute();

        // Suggestion follows
        $insertId = $conn->lastInsertId();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = :username WHERE id = :id');
        $userId = 'user' . $insertId;
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $userId);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $insertId);
        $stmt->execute();
        // End suggestion

        echo "Thank you for registering";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;

} else {

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('mywebsite.com/fblogin/index.php', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

Note that this assumes your auto-incrementing ID field is called `id` and the username field is called `username`.

Comment: Correct, my ID field is called ´id´. Added your suggestion, which returned: ´Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /home/username/mydomain/fblogin/index.php:141 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/username/mydomain/fblogin/index.php on line 141´

Since this is a Facebook login however, I fixed it by concatenating the string ´user_´ with the Facebook field ´id´ (the Facebook user id). Trusting that is unique enough.

Comment: It will be unique enough if you only have Facebook users registering. As some of the comments suggested, you could use `uniqid()` or similar to generate an almost certainly unique ID. The error is in the line `$stmt->bindParam(':username', 'user' . $insertId);` - the value must be passed by reference, i.e. be a variable pointing to memory. I've edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by just concatenating with Facebook's user id:

```
$firstname = $profile['first_name'];
$lastname = $profile['last_name'];
$email = $profile['email'];
$picture = $profile['picture']['url'];
$userstatus = "1";
$fbuserid = $profile['id'];
$defaultUsername = 'user_' . $fbuserid; // This line solved it. 

//<editor-fold desc="> Insert the data above this into the database">
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, picture, status, token, oauth_uid) 
VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :picture, :userstatus, :token, :oauth_uid)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':picture', $picture);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userstatus', $userstatus);
    $stmt->bindParam(':token', $fbuserid); // just oauth_uid stored in a better named column, also storing that with the line below
    $stmt->bindParam(':oauth_uid', $fbuserid); // this is the original of this and the one above
```